# How does C++ Preprocessors work?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am currently looking at open source C++ projects to learn more about C++.
One of the project I am look at is located at:

https://github.com/Myzilla-Web-Resources/OpenBlox/

I understand most of the source, but something I don't understand is how he is using the Preprocessors to declare a C++ class.

For instance,

static_init.h

```
#define DECLARE_STATIC_INIT(ClassName) \
static void static_init_func(); \
static OpenBlox::static_init_helper ClassName##_static_init_helper

namespace OpenBlox{
class static_init_helper{
    public:
        static_init_helper(init_func_type f){
            static_init::instance().add_init_func(f);
        }
};
```

Instance.h

```
#define DECLARE_CLASS(Class_Name) \
    virtual Instance* cloneImpl(); \
    virtual QString getClassName(); \
    virtual int wrap_lua(lua_State* L); \
    DECLARE_STATIC_INIT(Class_Name); \
    protected: \
        static QString ClassName; \
        static QString LuaClassName
```

Frame.h

```
namespace ob_instance{
class Frame: public GuiObject{
    public:
        Frame();
        virtual ~Frame();

        virtual void render();

        DECLARE_CLASS(Frame);
};
}
#endif
```

Please note that Frame.h inherited all of Instance.h functions/processors. 
Could someone explain to me how this work?

Comment: What exactly you don't understand in the code? `How this work` is very broad.

Comment: Sorry for being broad. I don't understand how he is using processors to declare classes. For example, when he called DECLARE_CLASS(Frame), it should add the class object "Frame" to a vector or some sort of array. So later he can declare it without actually creating the class again, if that make sense. Or am I thinking too hard?

Comment: The preprocessor works on a copy-paste and replacement textual basis. Nothing more to think about it.

Comment: @Kurieita: You might want to try configuring the compiler to emit the preprocessed (but uncompiled) source so that you can examine it, and see how the macros expand. In `gcc` and `clang` that is option `-E`.

Comment: It looks like a macro to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor is just a text find and replace, so in the `Frame` definition you showed, the preprocessor first sees `DECLARE_CLASS(Frame)` and replaces it with the content of the `DECLARE_CLASS` macro, becoming

```
namespace ob_instance{
class Frame: public GuiObject{
    public:
        Frame();
        virtual ~Frame();

        virtual void render();

        virtual Instance* cloneImpl();
        virtual QString getClassName();
        virtual int wrap_lua(lua_State* L);
        DECLARE_STATIC_INIT(Frame);
    protected:
        static QString ClassName;
        static QString LuaClassName;
};
}
```

(I cleaned up the formatting, in reality the entire replacement text is on one line).

It then backs up to just before the text it inserted, starts reading through again, and sees `DECLARE_STATIC_INIT(Frame)` and replaces that:

```
namespace ob_instance{
class Frame: public GuiObject{
    public:
        Frame();
        virtual ~Frame();

        virtual void render();

        virtual Instance* cloneImpl();
        virtual QString getClassName();
        virtual int wrap_lua(lua_State* L);
        static void static_init_func();
        static OpenBlox::static_init_helper Frame_static_init_helper;
    protected:
        static QString ClassName;
        static QString LuaClassName;
};
}
```

(The `##` is the [token concatenation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation))

Giving you the final `Frame` class definition.

As mentioned by Chris Beck in the comments, you can use the `-E` flag to gcc or clang to have the compiler output the preprocessed file instead of compiling it.